# Mongoose - How add documents to array that has id of that documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want transform original array stored with id of departments, pushing object document to same array. But when execute got "Converting circular structure to JSON".

Any idea how get all object document referenced by id and after replace the same array?

I create a Mutations.js for manage my functions transform JSON like remove _id to id and add href key with API url.

But first I want add departments object document to department key in original JSON.

**Controller User**

```
const boom = require('boom')
const User = require('../models/Users')
const Departments = require('../models/Departments')
const Mutation = require('../mutations')

    // GET all users
    exports.getUsers = async (req, reply) => {
        try {
            const users = await User.find()
            var json = [];
            users.map(item => {
                var element = Mutation.toJSON( item.toObject({ versionKey: false }) );
                element.departments = Mutation.rebuildArray(Departments, item.departments)
                json.push(element);
            })
            return json
        } catch (err) {
            throw boom.boomify(err)
        }
    }
```

**Mutation.js**

```
//Here convert document to JSON with structure needed
const toJSON = document => {
   document.id = document._id;
   delete document._id;
   return document;
}

//Create a array with document searched by id
const rebuildArray = (model, array) => {
      var newArray = [];
      array.map(item => {
        var element = model.findById(item);
      newArray.push(toJSON(element));
   })
   return newArray;
}

exports.rebuildArray = buildArray;
exports.toJSON = toJSON;
exports.addURL = addURL;
```

**I want recieve this JSON for example:**

[
    {
    "id": "f98nu4505fd782"
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "departments": [
        {
            "id": "d8nn83873434",
            "name": "Department 1 Name"
        },
        {
            "id": "9d8n892030e9",
            "name": "Department 2 Name"
        }
        ]
    }
]

**With this original JSON:**

[
    {
    "id": "f98nu4505fd782"
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "departments": ["d8nn83873434","9d8n892030e9"]
    }
]

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, if I understood your code properly. However, why do you convert to JSON here in this line?

    var element = Mutation.toJSON( item.toObject({ versionKey: false }) );

Keep in mind that JSON is a string (or stringified/serialized) representaion of a Javascript-object.

So, since "element" is supposedly an object, there is no need to stringify it via toJSON.

Which, by the way, your toJSON function in the "Mutation.js" module does not do. It simply modifies your object.

Comment: Yes @LongHike , the name of function toJSON can be not correct, but only modify key and in the future add other some keys, like url of API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use .[populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)('departments') of mongoose query.

Comment: This resolve my problem! `await User.find({}, (err, users) => {
            Departments.populate(users, { path: 'departments' }, (err, users) =>{
                reply.status(200).send(users);
            });
        }).select('-__v');`